# Distinguishing two cases for $\lim_L\delta_L^3 L^d$

Tags: analysis

> > Let $\lim_{L\to\infty}\delta_L=0$ and $\lim_{L\to\infty}L^{d/2}=\infty, d\geqslant 2~~~(*)$

Now two cases are distinguished.

**case I**

$\lim_{L\to\infty}\delta_L^3L^d=0$

**caseII**

The $\delta_L$'s are larger such that $\limsup_{L\to\infty}\delta_L^3L^d>0$.

---

My (maybe silly) question is: If $(*)$ how is it then possible that

(1.) $$\lim_{L\to\infty}\delta_L^3L^d=0$$

resp.

(2.) The $\delta_L$'s are larger such that $\limsup_{L\to\infty}\delta_L^3L^d>0$.

?

And why are this all cases?

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty}L^{d/2}=\infty$?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I correct it.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_L=1/L^{d/3}$, then $\delta_L^3L^{d/2}=L^{-d/2}\rightarrow 0$.

$\delta_L=1/L^{d/9}$, then $\delta_L^3L^{d/2}=L^{d/6}\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: Ok, you chose sequences that fullfill case 1 resp. case 2. But I do not see why this two cases are ALL cases in order to classify all $\delta_L$'s.

Comment: The only other option is $\lim\sup_{L\rightarrow\infty}\delta_L^3L^d<0$ which is absurd given that everything is nonnegative.